# How to resize width of scrollbar in WebEngineView?

Tags: css, qml, qt5, qtwebengine

I am using QML component WebEngineView, It has been observed that, scrollbar is by default implemented in WebEngineView, but there is no interface to change the width of scrollbar. This is required in my use case where I cannot use swipe, I can use only mouse drag operation on scrollbar of the WebEngineView in order to view all hidden part of the web content where length is outside the view port area. Since Scrollbar size of WebEngineView( default is very small 15pix )its quite difficult to drag exactly on the area and drag using mouse.

Can Some one suggest how to customize the scrollbar of WebEngineView?

or

I can find webengine source code, then modify and build for the purpose?

or

Any Style Can apply on WebEngineView ?

I am using Qt 5.6.2

**Qt Webengine Source code Observation:**
QML Webengineview is not set any scrollbar width internally, instead it uses back-end scrollbar probably of chrome’s.

Answer (score 0):

WebEngineView uses the scrollbar that comes from the Chromium backend and there is no QML or C++ API to customize it directly. However WebEngine supports to change these scrollbar styles in CSS, so the only thing you can do is to install a user script which applies a bigger width on all -webkit-scrollbar.

See this related example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-stylesheetbrowser-example.html

And your stylesheet could look like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 40px;
}
```